# File Upload control OnChange Event JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to build the page to upload the file by using AJAX, JQUERY and .Net HTTPHandler as in http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/async-file-upload-jquery-and

It works only for the first time I chose a file and uploaded it.  But it doesn't work when I select the file next time and doesn't show any error.

If I change the javascript event binding to the old school way like the following, it works perfectly.  But I want to use the JQuery Binding.  Is there anything I did wrongly?  Thanks.

```
<input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="input" onchange="return ajaxFileUpload();">
```

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>                           
                        <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" size="45" name="fileToUpload" class="fileToUpload" >
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

JQuery Binding Code:

```
<script>

    $().ready(function () {
        $(".fileToUpload").change(function() {
            $.ajaxFileUpload
                (
                    {
                        url: 'AJaxUploadHandler.ashx',
                        secureuri: false,
                        fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id' },
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                                if (data.error != '') {
                                    console.log(data.error);
                                } else {
                                    console.log(data.msg);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (data, status, e) {
                            alert(e);
                        }
                    }
                )

                return false;

        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use .on method as shown below and try again

```
  $(".fileToUpload").on('change', function() {
         ///// Your code
});
```

Comment: I have tried ur code, it's still the same.  I think, the problem is in the $.ajaxFileUpload library.  If I removed the ajax call and put simple console.log(xxx), it triggers every time I change the file.  But if I put the ajax call back, it doesn't work after 1st time.  So strange.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me.

```
$(document).on("change", "#inputId", function(){
     //Do something
});
```

For performance it is better to avoiding using `$(document)` and call the on() method on a wrapper div like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <input id="#inputId" type="file"/>
</div>

$("#wrapper").on("change", "#inputId", function(){
     //Do something
});
```

It has to do with Direct and delegated events: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. If I tried to upload the exact same file name at the exact same location. Then the change event would basically say no change. I ended up using a click even, checked for $(this).val() and call the the change event inside the click event handler.

```
$("input[type='file']").on('click', function () {
    if(!$(this).val()){
        //Initial Case when no document has been uploaded
        $("input[type='file']").change(function(){
            upload_file_setup(this);
        });
    }else{
        //Subsequent cases when the exact same document will be uploaded several times
        $(this).val('');
        $("input[type='file']").unbind('change');
        $("input[type='file']").change(function(){
            upload_file_setup(this);
        });
    }
});
```

The unbind may not be necessary but it works for me.

Comment: its good to unbind in case you have functions that stack events on elements

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("input[id='file-id']").on('change', function () {
   console.log('new file uploaded')
});
```

If you have multiple uploaded files to replace:
`input[id='file-id']` with `.file-class`

Answer (score 0):

```
// HTML code


<form action="" id="uploadImage">
    <input type="file" name="user_file" id="user_file" class="form-control" />
</form>

// jquery


$('input[type="file"][name="user_file"]').on('change', function() {

        var fd = new FormData($('#uploadImage')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>upload-profile?emp_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['emp_id'] ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: fd,
            cache: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.loading-overlay').css('display', 'flex');
                $('.avatar-md, .avatar-xxl').css('display', 'none');
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                $("#global-loader").fadeOut("slow");

                $("#user_file").val("");

                if (resp.msg == 'uploaded') {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: '<h6 class="text-success"><b>Profile Picture Uploaded...</b></h6>',
                        icon: 'success'
                    })
                    $('.avatar-md, .avatar-xxl').attr('src', resp.path)
                    $('.loading-overlay').css('display', 'none');
                    $('.avatar-md, .avatar-xxl').css('display', 'inline');
                }
            }
        })
    });


// Codeigniter Controller

function upload_profile()
{
    $emp_id = $_GET['emp_id'];

    $config['upload_path'] = "./documents/$emp_id";
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    
    $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['user_file']['name']);
    $rand = rand(1111, 9999);

    $file_name = $emp_id . "_" . date("Y_m_d") . "_" . $rand . "." . $ext[1];
    $config['file_name'] = $file_name;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);


    if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
        mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
    }
    $this->upload->do_upload('user_file');


    $array = array(
        'profile' => $file_name
    );

    $get_profile = $this->Employee_Model->upload_profile($array, $emp_id);

    $this->session->set_userdata('profile', $file_name);

    $filename = realpath('documents/' . $emp_id . '/' . $get_profile);

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'msg' => 'uploaded',
            'path' => base_url() . '/documents/' . $emp_id . '/' . $file_name
        )
    );

    try {
        if (!is_writable($filename))
            throw new Exception('File not writable');

        unlink('./documents/' . $emp_id . '/' . $get_profile);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        
    }
}


//Routes

$route['upload-profile'] = 'EmployeeController/upload_profile';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.